# Module not found while running server in django

Tags: python, django, settings

I am trying to start a new django project and I have decided to split my settings into production, staging and development following this tutorial https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2017/07/03/django-tip-20-working-with-multiple-settings-modules.html

On running `python manage.py runserver --settings=mysite.settings.development`,I get this error

```
 File "/home/user/crosspoint/crosspoint-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/user/crosspoint/crosspoint-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 61, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/user/crosspoint/crosspoint-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/user/crosspoint/crosspoint-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 68, in handle
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
  File "/home/user/crosspoint/crosspoint-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/user/crosspoint/crosspoint-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/user/crosspoint/crosspoint-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crosspoint.settings'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/user/crosspoint/crosspoint-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/user/crosspoint/crosspoint-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/user/crosspoint/crosspoint-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 367, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/home/user/crosspoint/crosspoint-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 208, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "/home/user/crosspoint/crosspoint-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 73, in __iter__
    return iter(self.settings)
  File "/home/user/crosspoint/crosspoint-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/user/crosspoint/crosspoint-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 45, in settings
    self._settings = self.configure_settings(self._settings)
  File "/home/user/crosspoint/crosspoint-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 144, in configure_settings
    databases = super().configure_settings(databases)
  File "/home/user/crosspoint/crosspoint-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 50, in configure_settings
    settings = getattr(django_settings, self.settings_name)
  File "/home/user/crosspoint/crosspoint-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/user/crosspoint/crosspoint-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/user/crosspoint/crosspoint-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crosspoint.settings'
```

I have tried checking the directory and everything seems to be fine. The project is practically empty. Any help with this please?

This is what I have in the development

```
from .base import *

DEBUG = True

INSTALLED_APPS += [
    'debug_toolbar',
]

MIDDLEWARE += ['debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware', ]

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    'JQUERY_URL': '',
}
```

This is how the directory looks like

```
crosspoint/
 |-- crosspoint/
 |    |-- __init__.py
 |    |-- settings/
 |    |    
 |    |    |-- base.py
 |    |    |-- ci.py
 |    |    |-- development.py
 |    |    |-- production.py
 |    |    +-- staging.py
 |    |-- urls.py
 |    +-- wsgi.py
 +-- manage.py
```

Comment: Can you post a directory listing of your settings folder?

Comment: Sure. Directory listing has been uploaded. Kindly take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake with the directory listing. Fixing the directory listing solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `__init__.py` file in your settings folder.  Without it, the directory is not a python module.

Comment: I added it (__init__.py) still not working. Thought __init__.py is compulsory if one is using Python 2.7. I am using python 3.6